# Homology of non-orientable surfaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homotopy-theory

I am rusty on the subject and trying to reconcile this statement (paraphrased from Wikipedia, so likely not precise): "If S is a non-orientable surface, then H1(S) contains a summand Z/2".  This is obviously false for a Mobius Strip which has the homotopy type of a circle, so is the disconnect that "surface" really should mean closed (compact without boundary) and the Mobius Strip with or without boundary is not? Thanks all.

Comment: They mean closed  (compact surface without boundary).

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Since the articles on the Mobius Strip call it a surface, clearly more rigor is required.

Comment: Keep in mind that anybody can edit a Wikipedia article, no matter how little do they understand about the subject. In particular, do not expect consistency.

Comment: Fair enough, I agree!